# Method_missing not running when it should

Tags: ruby, method-missing

I have a Team class in my program and I am trying to use method_missing
but instead of running the function when the method doesn't exist, it gives me an error:**"undefined method `hawks' for Team:Class (NoMethodError)"**

My code is as follows:

```
class Team
  attr_accessor :cust_roster, :cust_total_per, :cust_name, :cust_best_player
  @@teams = []
  def initialize(stats = {})
    @cust_roster = stats.fetch(:roster) || []
    @cust_total_per = stats.fetch(:per)
    @cust_name = stats.fetch(:name)
    @cust_best_player = stats.fetch(:best)
    @@teams << self

  end
  def method_missing(methId)
    str = methID.id2name
    Team.new(roster:[], per: 0, name: str.uppercase, best: 0)

  end



  class <<self
    def all_teams
      @@teams
    end
  end

end
hawks = Team.hawks
```

Comment: Do you not mean `hawks = Team.new.hawks`? `Team.hawks` attempts to invoke the non-existent class method `hawks`.

Comment: Or maybe `def self.method_missing`?

Comment: no that doesn't work and since Team.new is already a function it won't run method_missing

Comment: @ScottJ `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

Comment: try to do `hawks = Team.new`. 
then do `hawks = hawks.hawks`

Comment: @davidhu2000 fetch': key not found: :roster (KeyError)
 from openfile.rb:126:in `initialize'
 from openfile.rb:148:in `new'
 from openfile.rb:148:in `<main>'

Comment: `method_missing` is an instance method, meaning it must be invoked on an instance of the class `Team`. `Team.new` returns an instance of `Team`, not a method. `new` may of course have arguments.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried what you said, and it still didn't work

Comment: That's because there apparently are other problems. My point was that `Team.hawks` was incorrect. I haven't looked at the rest of your code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the error is: fetch': key not found: :roster (KeyError)
 from openfile.rb:126:in `initialize'
 from openfile.rb:148:in `new'
 from openfile.rb:148:in `<main>'

Comment: if you are using method_missing to simply assign the name of the team, why don't you do that in the initialize method?

Comment: hawks = Team.new(roster:[], per: 0, name: "HAWKS", best: 0)

Comment: @davidhu2000 im trying to reduce the amount of code i write

Comment: @ davidhu2000 im also trying to learn about method_missing

Comment: @CarySwoveland but if i take out the hawks = Team.hawks, it doesn't give me any errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code. Let's go through one by one.

From the documentation,

> method_missing(*args) private
> Invoked by Ruby when obj is sent a message it cannot handle.

Here `message` refers to the `method`. In ruby, whenever you're calling a method on an object, you're actually `send`ing a `message` to the `object`

To better understand this, try this in the irb shell.

```
1+2
=> 3
1.send(:+,2)
=> 3
```

Here 1 and 2 are objects of `Fixnum` class. You can confirm that by using `1.class`. Ok, back to your question. So, a `method_missing` method should be called on an instance.

```
team = Team.new
team.hawks
```

If you try the above piece of code, you'll get an error saying `'fetch': key not found: :roster (KeyError)`

You can get around this by passing a `default value` as the second parameter to `fetch` method. Replace your `initialize` method with

```
def initialize(stats = {})
  @cust_roster = stats.fetch(:roster, [])
  @cust_total_per = stats.fetch(:per, 0)
  @cust_name = stats.fetch(:name, "anon")
  @cust_best_player = stats.fetch(:best, "anon")
  @@teams << self
```

end

If you execute the script, you'll get a `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` because of a small typo in this line.

```
str = methID.id2name
```

In the method definition, you're receiving an argument with the name of `methId` but inside you're trying to call `methID`. Fix it with

```
str = methId.id2name
```

If you execute your script, you'll again get an error saying `undefined method uppercase for "hawks":String (NoMethodError)`

This is because there is no `uppercase` method on strings. You should instead use the `upcase` method.

```
Team.new(roster:[], per: 0, name: str.upcase, best: 0)
```

and you should be good to go.

For more, see http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/method_missing

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Team
  attr_accessor :cust_roster, :cust_total_per, :cust_name, :cust_best_player
  @@teams = []
  def initialize(stats = {roster: [], per: 0, name: "", best: 0}) # I added the default values here. 
    @cust_roster = stats.fetch(:roster)
    @cust_total_per = stats.fetch(:per)
    @cust_name = stats.fetch(:name)
    @cust_best_player = stats.fetch(:best)
    @@teams << self

  end
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    self.cust_name = name.to_s.upcase
  end

  class << self
    def all_teams
      @@teams
    end
  end

end

team_hawks = Team.new #=> create an instance of Team class, I renamed the object to avoid confusions. 
team_hawks.hawks      #=> called method_missing which assigned the cust_name variable to "HAWKS"

team_hawks.cust_name  #=> HAWKS, so cust_name is assigned to be hawks. This is to check if the assignment worked.
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.